# Cannot get jQuery alerts to work in Google Apps script

Tags: jquery, google-apps-script

I am not able to get jQuery alerts to work in my GAS project. I am able to include the basic jquery library like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

However, if I try to include these for using jAlert:

```
<script src="https://jquery.alerts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="https://jquery.alerts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

I get an error saying: "net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED" in console.

How do I include the jquery alerts library for use in GAS?

Note: Is jquery.alerts.js website active? I don't see any content there (I am new to this. I don't know if this website is supposed to exist or no).

Comment: you need to save the file jquery.alerts.js and .css to a https webserver.  Google Sites, or dropbox has the ability to host the files.

Comment: hi. thanks for the reply. are there any publicly hosted jquery alerts file that you know? I thought since this is a commonly used library, it would be easily available on some public webserver.

Comment: jQueryUI (Which you have already included) has the dialog function built-in: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add jquery.alerts source on you google apps script project.
In Google apps script project create html file **jquery.alerts.css.html** and put in it source code in tag **style** like

`<style>
    popup_container {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    min-width: 300px; /* Dialog will be no smaller than this */
    /*...and other code*/
</style>`

Than create html file **jquery.alerts.js.html** and put in it source code in tag **script** like

`<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($) {

        $.alerts = {
            verticalOffset: -75,
            horizontalOffset: 0,
            repositionOnResize: true,
        /*...and other code*/
</script>`

Then when you can use this library with html service. Example:

`<html>
    <?!= include('jquery.alerts.css.html'); ?>
    <?!= include('jquery.alerts.js.html'); ?>
        <head>
            <base target="_top">
        </head>
        <body>
           <div>
              <a href="http://google.com">Click Me!</a>
           </div>
        </body>
</html>`

Comment: did this and worked great, thank you!. (note for other users: you have to create a template output from file and use the google apps server include. details here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices )